# How to tell IE a HTML file on my disk is not a security risk?

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer

Our build script creates a HTML log with some embedded javascript. When I open that in Internet Explorer, I get the yellow warning bar that IE has blocked running "scripts or activex controls".

Since it is a local file, I cannot add it to trusted sites (IE expects a domain here).

I do not want to change security settings for the default zone.

Any idea how to permanently unblock it?

IE version is 7.0.5730.13 on XP Pro.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Embed the [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628.aspx):

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx for more information on this.

Answer (score 3):

You could add [The Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx) to the document so that IE will act as if it's from a certain security zone.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want to hear but I'm not sure you can. Does Firefox/Opera/Safari complain when you run it in any of those? If it works then that seems like the simplest solution to me.

Comment: That would mean either changing the build script to look for whereever firefox is installed, or changing the default browser. Not simple, or to many side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Local Machine Zone and configure security for it:

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/IE/community/columns/improvements.mspx

Comment: That's only something that should be done temporarily. If you leave it configured then you run the risk of a saved web page you open down the track running with elevated privileges on your machine. Using the Mark of the Web feature would be safer.

Comment: I agree, at least for this situation.
I've used relaxed Local Machine Zone security to test IE handling of javascript on web pages locally - in that case MOTW was not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can always enable **ActiveX**. I've tested this on Internet Explorer 11, but should work on earlier version of IE:

**Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security** :

```
(✓) Allow active content from CDs to run on My Computer
(✓) Allow active content to run in files on My Computer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a local server and save such files in a domain you can now add to the trusted sites, but opening the file in any other browser than IE is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if it's only IE you need to view it in is to save it as a .hta file.

This makes it a HTML application.

It's as simple as changing the suffix to .hta. Although there are other options you can specify.

For more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx