# print automatically html file with powershell

Tags: html, powershell, printing

I want to print an html file to the default printer with powershell. So lets say I have the file c:\test.html with the text:

```
<html>
<p> hello <b>world</b></p>
<html>
```

How could I print test.html to the default printer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you are interested in printing the rendered output rather that the html source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
get-content c:\test.html  | out-printer
```

Print to default printer.

Edit:

if you need print rendered htlm page:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("c:\test.html")
$ie.ExecWB(6,2)
```

Edit after comments:

I can run this in a testprint.ps1 file:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("c:\test.html")
while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 }
$ie.ExecWB(6,2)
while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 }
$ie.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! Almost perfect. I see that I stay with IE running, should I run a "close" command? I tried $ie.Quit() and $ie.Close() but had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: To dipose the IE session open as $ie you have to call $ie.quit(). This not close other IE sessions open. Can you try again closing all other IE session?

Comment: If I put the quit it does not print. Tried this: "While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }
$ie.Quit()" but it doesn't print.

Comment: Did a harcode 5 seconds sleep and it works. Need to do a wait in the main thread or something like that.

Comment: Glad it helped! see OLECMDID, OLECMDEXECOPT on msdn, are the values of ExecWB member!

Comment: I get `Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040100 (DRAGDROP_E_NOTREGISTERED))
At line:4 char:1
+ $ie.ExecWB(6,2);`

Comment: @Yoda I saw that error. I fixed it by removing the `while`s, so just `Start-Sleep -seconds 3`

Comment: Also, if you get an `The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)`, this solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/721519/1754517