# Powershell - How to print rendered HTML to a network printer?

Tags: powershell

I need to print an HTML file to a remote printer queue.

I've had a read of this question:
[print automatically html file with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189299/print-automatically-html-file-with-powershell)

which says to do this:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("c:\test.html")
while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -second 3 }
$ie.ExecWB(6,2)
while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -second 3 }
$ie.quit()
```

But this uses Internet Explorer, and that only allows you to print to the local printer.
The printer is on a shared standard TCP port.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
More Info:

I have been tasked with the creation about 2,000 new Print Queue's on W2K12 using Powershell v4, which I have working fine. But I'd now like to confirm the success of these queue's by sending a nicely formatted html test print to each of the many remote print servers from my central management server. Without having these 2,000 queue's mapped to my management server, how can I achieve this task, as the Out-Printer Cmdlet prints the sheet in its Raw html tag format and not its Marked up nice format.

Comment: Is the remote printer a shared printer? Or pure queue? IP address only?

Comment: Hi Austin, please see my edit.

Comment: From memory, it's possible to create a local printer which prints to a remote port. E.g. In Win7, 'Devices & Printers' > 'Add a Printer' > 'Add a local printer' > 'Creat a new port' > 'Type of Port = Standard TCP/IP Port' > Next etc. Apps should see this as a 'local' printer.