# Loading XML/XSLT in IE using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt, logging

I'm building a neat-looking logging system inspired by [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/using-xml-technologies-for-enhancing-log-files-r3222). My general setup is as follows:

1. I have a Javascript enhanced html-page.
2. I have a XML document that I use as a testlog for now.
3. I have a XSLT file used for converting the XML to HTML (and prettifying it).

Because I want to dynamically load XML log files in my page I use the following code in the html doc:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult(name) {
    if(name == null)
        xml = loadXMLDoc("testlog.xml");
    else
        xml = loadXMLDoc(name);
    xsl = loadXMLDoc("layout.xsl");
    document.getElementById("logview").innerHTML = "";
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        document.getElementById("logview").innerHTML = ex;
    }
        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById("logview").appendChild(resultDocument);
}
```

What it does: displayResult() is called when the user has selected a local file to load and is passed the name of the local file. The script will then try to load the XML file and the XSL file from the disc and transform the XML to HTML before it replaces the contents of a DIV by this new HTML.

My XML looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunTimeLog>
  <LogHeader>
    <StartDate>02-09-2013</StartDate>
    <StartTime>09:52</StartTime>
    <Platform>Windows 8</Platform>
    <MemoryTotal>1,048,576 kB</MemoryTotal>
  </LogHeader>
  <LogEvents>

    <LogEvent id="1">
      <Type>Warning</Type>
      <TimeIndex>00:01:34</TimeIndex>
      <File>application.cc</File>
      <Function>SomeFunction()</Function>
      <LineNumber>314</LineNumber>
      <Message>This is just a randum warning, nothing to worry about!</Message>
    </LogEvent>
    <LogEvent id="2">
      <Type>Debug</Type>
      <TimeIndex>00:01:34</TimeIndex>
      <File>application.cc</File>
      <Function>SomeFunction()</Function>
      <LineNumber>314</LineNumber>
      <Message>This is just a randum warning, nothing to worry about!</Message>
    </LogEvent>

  </LogEvents>
</RunTimeLog>
```

And my XSLT has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <font face="Arial" size="3" color="#000000">
      <b>Run info:</b>
    </font>
    <br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="RunTimeLog/LogHeader"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <font face="Arial" size="3" color="#000000">
      <b>Log:</b>
    </font>
    <br/>
    <br/>
            <table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolorlight="#000000" bordercolordark="#ffffff" bordercolor="#000000">
                <tr>
                    <td width="3%"  bgcolor="#000000"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><b><center>#</center></b></font></td>
                    <td width="20%" bgcolor="#000000"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><b><center>Time</center></b></font></td>
                    <td width="23%" bgcolor="#000000"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><b><center>File</center></b></font></td>
                    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#000000"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><b><center>Function</center></b></font></td>
                    <td width="4%"  bgcolor="#000000"><font size="2" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><b><center>Line</center></b></font></td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="RunTimeLog/LogEvents"/>
            </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

Now, the problem I'm having is the following: this all works nicely in Firefox, which uses the XMLHttpRequest() to load the files. But in IE ActiveX is used and the script errors on the line

```
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
```

with the error

```
  SCRIPT16389: The stylesheet does not contain a document element.  The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.
```

I have tried multiple solutions given in other threads and forums: changing MIME type, using different root nodes, even replacing the XML and XSLT with different documents which work a 100% sure. Also, if I just use the XML and XSLT using an href in IE, it displays withouth a problem. This makes me belvieve the problem is in the loading functionality of the ActiveXObject. Is there someone here who can shed a light on what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance,

Yuri

Comment: Well debug the code, check `console.log(xsl.parseError.errorCode)`, `console.log(xsl.parseError.reason)`, `console.log(xsl.documentElement !== null)`. Also which version of IE do you use? What is the MIME type the XSLT document is been served with?

Comment: Your code is backward. You should use the native XmlHttpRequest object if it's present, and only try falling back to the ActiveX object if it's not.

Comment: @EricLaw If I reverse the if statement it tells me "Access Denied" on the "xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);" statement below.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm using the 10.0.8 version of IE, and tried older versions too in compatability mode. I'm currently not explicitly serving in a certain MIME type. Everything is local (and I want to keep it that way). The console-logs give me 0, "", and false respectively, so that means the loading failed right? Seeing as that xsl.documentElement is NULL?

Comment: If you are using HTML documents loaded from the file system but have script and ActiveX enabled then for the IE branch I would simply use `if (window.ActiveXObject) then { var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0'); doc.async = false; doc.load(dname); if (doc.parseError.errorCode === 0) { return doc; } else { // need to handle parse error here }} else { // code for other browsers goes here }`.

Comment: Are you loading your page over HTTP or FILE?

Comment: I'm loading over FILE. I managed to fix it in a different way (by including JS in the HTMl by injecting it with the XSL). Still wondering why it doesn't work though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell IE a HTML file on my disk is not a security risk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721446/how-to-tell-ie-a-html-file-on-my-disk-is-not-a-security-risk)